# How do you handle headers that include headers with a makefile in C?

Tags: c, makefile

Suppose you have a file called file.c.

- `file.c` includes `header1.h`
- `header1.h` includes `header2.h`

Here's what I have for the makefile:

```
file.x: file.o
        -gcc file.o -o file.x

file.o: file.c header1.h header2.h
        -gcc file.c header1.h header2.h
```

I am confused about how to handle when header2.h includes header1.h.

Is this line redundant? Or is it good style to show dependencies?

```
file.c header1.h header2.h
```

**Update:** I apologize for the confusion. I have reverted the edits I made to the question. The current makefile is the one I posted in the original question that Jonathan's answer refers to.

Comment: You don't need to feed header files to compiler. It will find them anyway.

Comment: `-gcc`, really?  Don't you want `make` to fail if the compile fails?

Comment: I'm a newbie at C... What do you suggest that would be better?

Comment: Drop the `-` from `-gcc`. If you want `make` to build as much as it can, use `make -k`; it continues after errors until it cannot build anything else.  Don't use `make -i` or `.IGNORE` in general; that leads to trouble.  And the `-gcc` will leave the overall `make` successful even though the build failed — which is usually bad news.

Comment: Almost everything is wrong with your code, but the answer to your question is that you need to perform dependency analysis. GCC can do this for you (I believe with some variant of an `-M` option), but it's a little non-trivial, and you essentially need to run two passes over your files.

Comment: @KerrekSB, there's no reason to run two passes.  If you just generate the dependency files whenever you compile, they'll always be correct. The first time you build, there won't be any dependencies, but since you haven't built yet there won't be any object files anyway, so every target will be out of date and built as expected.

Comment: Ok, so I've edited my makefile. I guess it is trivial now with just one file, but is what I have correct?

Comment: Please please please do not edit source in place in questions, as it makes responses inapplicable. If you're going to post updated source, do it in an additional section headed by "Update:" or some such.

Comment: Okay, I will revert the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original version of the question contained the following lines in the `makefile`:

```
file.o: file.c header1.h header2.h
        -gcc file.c header1.h header2.h
```

My answer addresses the original version of the question, before it got fixed up.

<sup>Note that the compilation line generates the executable `a.out` unless the compiler objects to compiling the header files.  You should have `-c` in the command line.</sup>

---

A couple of issues:

1. In a `makefile`, when does the object file need rebuilding?

   Answer: when the source file or one of the headers it includes changes.

   Subsidiary Q: what does this dependency line mean:

   ```
   file.o: file.c header1.h header2.h
   ```

   Subsidiary A: `file.o` needs rebuilding if the source file or one of the headers it includes changes.
2. If you stipulate: `header1.h` depends on `header2.h`, what's going to happen to `header1.h` when you change `header2.h`?

   Answer: nothing.  You don't compile `header1.h` per se.  It is the object files that change.
3. If you stipulate the `file.c` depends on `header1.h` or `header2.h` or both, what's going to happen to `file.c` when you change one of the headers?

   Answer: nothing again.  You don't change `file.c`; you recompile the object file again.

So, the dependency portion of your object file rule is fine (within limitations related to automatic dependency generation).  There is no point in a rule that says the source file depends on the headers; in fact, the source file does not directly depend on the headers.  (It indirectly depends on them in that if the header contents change so that what was valid code is no longer valid code, nothing will compile until the source is fixed.  But that is slightly off the subject.)

Hard-coding the dependencies is problematic; they change.  On the other hand, generating the dependencies automatically is fiddly.  There are GCC options (like `-M`, `-MM`, `-MF`,  `-MG`, `-MP`, `-MQ`, `-MD`, `-MMD`, `-MT`, `-H` — such an abundance of options tells you there are issues here!) to assist, and GNU `make` has 'conditional inclusion' to include dependency files if they exist and not witter if they don't.  These can help.  Look up `makedepend`, `mkdep` and related commands for other ways of automating that.

---

Ignoring automatic dependency generation, your makefile might read:

```
FILES.o = file.o

file.x: ${FILES.o}
        ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${FILES.o} 

file.o: file.c header1.h header2.h
```

`make` will provide a command to compile `file.c` into `file.o`.

When your program grows to use `other.o` too, you simply add `other.o` to the macro `FILES.o` (that's why it is a plural name).  You might add dependency information too.  If you need libraries too, then you can add options to the link line:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
LDLIBS  = -llocal

FILES.o = file.o other1.o other2.o

file.x: ${FILES.o}
        ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${FILES.o} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

file.o: file.c header1.h header2.h
```

Note that the libraries should go after the object files.  Listing libraries before object files is apt to lead to link-time failures on other platforms, to the irritation of those trying to build your software.

Comment: Oh ok, so that means it is sufficient to just write "file.o: file.c"? Because the headers are already included in the file?

Comment: And for the next line: "gcc file.c"?

Comment: "So, your object file rule is fine" -- The dependencies are fine (though they should be autogenerated), but the compilation command is quite wrong.

Comment: You need `file.o: file.c header1.h header2.h` somewhere to tell `make` that if any of the 3 files changes, it needs to rebuild `file.o`.  Just listing `file.c` as a dependency means that `header1.h` could change but the object file would not be rebuilt.

Comment: @CowZow "so that means it is sufficient to just write "file.o: file.c"? Because the headers are already included in the file? " -- No, that's not fine, and that's not at all what he said.

Comment: In the compilation line, you do not list the headers explicitly; you only list the source file.  So, you should have `${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c file.c` or thereabouts, though `make` would provide that for you automatically.  The exact way you spell `file.c` varies a bit; you'll see a variety of notations used.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to make sure I understand.. So the line `file.o: file.c header1.h header2.h` indicates the dependencies of file.o, and so whenever one of those files changes then the object file is recompiled. So it is not sufficient to just write `file.o: file.c` since, even though the headers are included in file.c, it would not have recompiled if one of the headers have changed?

Comment: Correct; you need to list the headers so that when they change, the object file is rebuilt.  `make` will infer the dependency on the source file, so it is not crucial to list it, but it is more or less conventional to do so.

Comment: "make will infer the dependency on the source file" -- Even if dependencies are explicitly given? Even if GNU make does that, I wouldn't count on it generally.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you very much for the explanation. I think I understand this better. I really appreciate how patient you were!

Comment: If the name of the object file is directly derived by suffix substitution, even 7th Edition `make` managed that, IIRC.  If it wasn't 7th Edition, it was in System III or System V `make`.  Like I said, it is conventional to list it anyway, but no — it actually isn't needed in any version of `make` you're likely to have used in the last twenty-odd years (subject to contradiction by definitive documentation to the contrary — but I'm not sure I'll be worried about Apollo or Ultrix).